# Set pointer to pointer data in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Im stuck in creation a function which should return a struct containing pointers to pointers. The problem is that i don't get access to the data :/

The problem is like:

```
struct openGLmodel
{

    struct subM
    {

        Vec3*      positions;
        Vec3*      normals;

        int        nbrVertices;

        int        nbrTriangles;
        int*       triangleIndices;
    };

    dim_type  subModelCount;
    subM*     subModel;
}
```

the function is constructing the model by:

```
openGLmodel createModel(..model data)
{

openGLmodel model;

std::vector<openGLmodel::subM>* subModels = new std::vector<openGLmodel::subM>; 

std::vector<Vec3>* positions = new std::vector<Vec3>;
std::vector<Vec3>* normals = new std::vector<Vec3>;

int subModelIndex = 0;

for(...all vertices...)
{
    ... //extracting positions and normal vectors

    positions->push_back(pos);
    normals->push_back(normal);

    if(positions->size() >= 65536)
    {
        subModels->push_back(openGLmodel::subM());

        subModels->at(subModelIndex).positions = positions->data();
        subModels->at(subModelIndex).normals = normals->data();


        std::vector<Vec3>* positions = new std::vector<Vec3>;
        std::vector<Vec3>* normals = new std::vector<Vec3>;

        subModelIndex++;
    }
}

...
... 


model.subModel = new openGLmodel::subM[subModelIndex]();

for(int i=0; i<subModelIndex; i++)
{
    model.subModel[i] = openGLmodel::subM();

    model.subModel[i].positions = subModels->data()[i].positions;
    model.subModel[i].normals = subModels->data()[i].normals;

}

return model;

}
```

The subModels is containing the correct data but the model.subModel is not. How can i get the model to get access to the data in the vectors? Seems to be wrong in the last for-loop..

Comment: I don't see `model` being used *anywhere* beyond its declaration. I do, however, see two perfect memory leaks  before the increment in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you're accessing:

```
 model.subModel[i]
```

when that is just of type:

```
subM*     subModel;
```

you're accessing memory that is not supposed to be accessed.

On a side note, your code is overcomplicated and dangerous.
You can cut most of the pointers, that you don't actually need.

```
std::vector<openGLmodel::subM>* subModels = new std::vector<openGLmodel::subM>; 

std::vector<Vec3>* positions = new std::vector<Vec3>;
std::vector<Vec3>* normals = new std::vector<Vec3>;
```

becomes

```
std::vector<openGLmodel::subM> subModels;    
std::vector<Vec3> positions;
std::vector<Vec3> normals;
```

and your structure

```
struct openGLmodel
{

    struct subM
    {

        Vec3 positions;
        Vec3 normals;
        int  nbrVertices;

        int        nbrTriangles;
        std::vector<int> triangleIndices;
    };

    dim_type  subModelCount;
    subM*     subModel;
}
```

Should you need to reuse existing vectors and not copy them around, you can just use a reference to an vector and initialize it in the constructor's initialization list.

Comment: okay thanks, but lets say that submodels is pointing to the right data. how do i get this data to be known by the model.

why cant i access model.submodel[i]? and how can i substituse this part:

`model.subModel = new openGLmodel::subM[subModelIndex]();

for(int i=0; i<subModelIndex; i++)
{
    model.subModel[i] = openGLmodel::subM();

    model.subModel[i] = subModels->data()[i];

}

return model;`